# How to extract the destination operand from an LLVM branch op

Tags: llvm

Here is a snippet of (non-sensical) C++ code that is trying to build a conditional branch using LLVM:

```
      Value fval = other ? otherval : zeroVal;
      rewriter.create<LLVM::CondBrOp>(loc, pred, block1, block2, fval);
      rewriter.setInsertionPointToEnd(block1);
      Value trueVal = load(pElem);
      rewriter.create<LLVM::BrOp>(loc, trueVal, block2);
      rewriter.setInsertionPointToEnd(block2);
      lvals.push_back(val); // SmallVector
```

The "val" in that last statement should be fval if the conditional branch jumped straight to block2 or it should be trueVal if conditional branch went first to block1.

How can i extract the right "val" (depending on which way the branch went)?

A related question: what are the operand arguments in the branch ops used for?

Comment: One generally adds a store to the front of each branch, so a variable in ram contains 1 of the branch went this way and 0 if that way. Or if you need it before execution, you could try folding the condition to a constant; there are funciton in ConstantFolding.h.